# Functional programming model bean definition and spring-cloud-function + spring-cloud-stream integration

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

Hi all and a specially spring team!

How can I pipeline spring-cloud-function with spring-cloud-stream in functional Bean programming model style?

For example I have pom.xml with both dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and let's say I would like to do next:

1. send via http payload string via spring-cloud-function (webflux)
2. uppercase it using my toUpperCase function
3. and finally send forward into my pipeline to installed binder (kafka/rabbit/test-binder)

so I'm expecting implement it like so:

```java
@Log4j2
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudFunctionStreamApplication {

  /**
   * can I sent result of that function to my broker without any
   * explicitly defined output.send(...) execution?
   */
  @Bean
  public Function<String, String> toUpperCase() {
    return arg -> {
      var res = arg.toUpperCase();
      log.info("toUpperCase: {}", res);
      return res;
    };
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(
      SpringCloudFunctionStreamApplication.class,
      "--spring.cloud.function.definition=toUpperCase",
      "--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=toUpperCase"
    );
  }
}
```

so when I'm using HTTPie to send a payload, like so:

```sh
echo 'hello' | http :8080/toUpperCase
```

spring-cloud-function seems to works fine, and I can see expected log:

```
2019-06-09 21:20:36.978 ...SpringCloudFunctionStreamApplication : toUpperCase: hello
```

same think if I'm publishing message via rabbitmq management web ui, but how I can pipeline from one to another

So my question related to [according to spring documentation which says that I can use spring-cloud-stream as well:](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/2.1.1.RELEASE/#_introduction) Wrappers for @Beans of type Function, Consumer and Supplier, exposing them to the outside world as either HTTP endpoints and/or message stream listeners/publishers with RabbitMQ, Kafka etc., but I cannot understand how?

At the moment, unfortunately, I can only manually publish message to spring-cloud-stream binder using Source [see example here](https://github.com/daggerok/spring-cloud-function-stream-integration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/SpringCloudFunctionStreamApplication.java#L43), but it's of course what I want to know if it's possible to avoid with spring, magically...

Can please anybody tell me (maybe Gary Russell, Dave Sawyer, Artem Bilan, Oleg Zhurakousky or anybody else who knows): what do I missed and how I should configure my app or which props I should add in my application.properties, etc?

Thanks!

**Update**

It was quite a while, but I've decide post here a solution...

In short: fixed commit is here: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-cloud-function-stream-integration/commit/35325465b81bb869c31ec7892f413ab891d6d0fd

So basically with StreamBridge I can connect spring-cloud-function with spring-cloud-stream ... I just can send anything a want in proper destination, configurable for needed pipeline chain right from  a body of my spring-cloud-function

See details in mentioned updated repository (branch fixed if you wish)

Cheers!

---

Regards,
Maksim

Comment: Maksim, if I understand correctly you want `http -> function(s) -> rabbit` correct?

Comment: Hello Oleg! Yes, I just want provide functions definitions for both: spring-cloud-function and spring-cloud-stream and somethere configure data flow pipeline... So wherever spring-cloud-function will be triggered by someone via rest, it's output should pipeline forward next to spring-cloud-stream, according to configuration by using rabbit/karfka. At the moment I was able forward data from function into queue only manually, but it would be awesome if I should not inject Source and use it to manually to pass data into queue

Comment: Maksim, is it possible to define toUpperCase outside SpringBootApplication and still wrap it into rest endpoints ? im trying to load a large number of functions from a third party library and i want to create endpoints for all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maksim

This is not ideal but given that we implemented initial function support within the scope of the existing binders there are some limitations. I'll explain, but first here is the fully functioning code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleFunctionRabbitDemoApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleFunctionRabbitDemoApplication.class,
            "--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=uppercase");
    }

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> consume() {
        return v -> processor.input().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(v).build());
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return value -> value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Basically there is a bit of a missmatch. On stream side we have binders and on he function side we have adapters. You are effectively (with your requirement) attempting to bridge the two into a pipeline. So. . .

Let's look at the binders first.

The uppercase function is bound to `input` and `output` channels provided by the message channel binders (rabbit or kafka), effectively creating an internal pipeline `input -> uppercase -> output`. It is also exposed as REST endpoint by s-c-function, however, s-c-function does not have access to the mentioned pipeline. In fact it actually has it's own pipeline `request -> uppercase -> reply`. 
So what we need to do is to bridge the two concepts together and that is effectively what I did.

- You inject your app with `Processor` binding which contains references to the channels `uppercase` is bound to.
- You invoke `consume()` via REST `http://localhost:8080/consume/blah`.
- You send a Message to the input channel of the `uppercase` function

In he future to simplify this we simply need to create a binder-like version of web adapter, so please feel free to raise a feature request. But as you can see the current workaround is not all that involved.

Comment: Hey Oleg Zhurakousky,
Thanks for your feedback! I have two questions:
1) Do we really need processor in this case? I thought Source would be enough in case we only need put data into pipeline.
2) Did you missed @EnableBinding(Processor.class) or it's not required anymore?

For example you provided, I'm getting an error : Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.integrationFlowCreator.channel#0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Comment: Yes, Source would suffice. With regard to EnableBinding, yes it is not required in the above case, but you'd need the latest version of stream or add EnableBInding back

Comment: I finally have it fixed just like I wanted from beginning) It was nice with new spring cloud stream functional approach using StreamBridge.. Just in case if anyone would interested: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-cloud-function-stream-integration/commit/35325465b81bb869c31ec7892f413ab891d6d0fd

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a question to Oleg Zhurakousky. Would be glad if answered

If I use `@Bean Supplier<Pojo>...` for binding the output destination, how to invoke it from a `@Service` class or `@Controller` class every time a new `Pojo` is to be sent to Kafka/Rabbit.

`Supplier` only exposes a `get()` method.

I am writing only the producer which will write a custom `Pojo` to Kafka and a different application is the Consumer. The functional approach is clearer for a `Consumer<Pojo>...` where it would just read from the Kafka and process. The `Supplier<Pojo>...` part for the producer is not clear.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nui3hXzcbK0&t=3478s

Comment: Have you read this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources. Suppliers are special functions that will be polled using internal poller which is configurable

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek

You can utilise `EmitterProcessor` as described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_foreign_event_driven_sources). The provided example uses rest endpoint as he actual source of data, but as you can see it doesn't meter since all you need to do is invoke `onNext` operation of the `EmitterProcessor` passing your event from Service.